# Netezza connection with Spark / Scala JDBC

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, netezza

I've set up Spark 2.2.0 on my Windows machine using Scala 2.11.8 on IntelliJ IDE.  I'm trying to make Spark connect to Netezza using JDBC drivers.

I've read through [this link](https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2016/02/19/reading-netezza-data-spark-sql-data-souce/) and added the `com.ibm.spark.netezza`jars to my project through Maven.  I attempt to run the Scala script below just to test the connection:

```
package jdbc
object SimpleScalaSpark {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, SQLContext}
    import com.ibm.spark.netezza

    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("SimpleScalaSpark")
      .getOrCreate()

    val sqlContext = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("SimpleScalaSpark")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

val nzoptions = Map("url" -> "jdbc:netezza://SERVER:5480/DATABASE",
  "user" -> "USER",
  "password" -> "PASSWORD",
  "dbtable" -> "ADMIN.TABLENAME")

val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.ibm.spark.netezza").options(nzoptions).load()
  }
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
17/07/27 16:28:17 ERROR NetezzaJdbcUtils$: Couldn't find class org.netezza.Driver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.netezza.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:38)
    at com.ibm.spark.netezza.NetezzaJdbcUtils$$anonfun$getConnector$1.apply(NetezzaJdbcUtils.scala:49)
    at com.ibm.spark.netezza.NetezzaJdbcUtils$$anonfun$getConnector$1.apply(NetezzaJdbcUtils.scala:46)
    at com.ibm.spark.netezza.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at jdbc.SimpleScalaSpark$.main(SimpleScalaSpark.scala:20)
    at jdbc.SimpleScalaSpark.main(SimpleScalaSpark.scala)
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:netezza://SERVER:5480/DATABASE
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at com.ibm.spark.netezza.NetezzaJdbcUtils$$anonfun$getConnector$1.apply(NetezzaJdbcUtils.scala:54)
    at com.ibm.spark.netezza.NetezzaJdbcUtils$$anonfun$getConnector$1.apply(NetezzaJdbcUtils.scala:46)
    at com.ibm.spark.netezza.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at jdbc.SimpleScalaSpark$.main(SimpleScalaSpark.scala:20)
    at jdbc.SimpleScalaSpark.main(SimpleScalaSpark.scala)
```

I have two ideas:

1) I don't don't believe I actually installed any Netezza JDBC driver, though I thought the jars I brought into my project from the link above was sufficient.  Am I just missing a driver or am I missing something in my Scala script?

2) In the same link, the author makes mention of starting the Netezza Spark package:

> For example, to use the Spark Netezza package with Spark’s interactive
>   shell, start it as shown below:
>
> $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell –packages
>   com.ibm.SparkTC:spark-netezza_2.10:0.1.1
>   –driver-class-path~/nzjdbc.jar

I don't believe I'm invoking any package apart from `jdbc` in my script.  Do I have to add that to my script?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your spark-submit command? Note that it needs both `--jars` and `--driver-class-path` to load your JDBC Driver.

Comment: @philantrovert I believe I setup IntelliJ to start Spark when I run my Scala script, but not certain what the spark-submit command is defaulted to start with.  Regardless, you're saying my spark-submit command should be updated to include the --packages and --driver-class-path like (2) above?

Comment: I also did try running this in the command line before executing the script, but unfortunately still got the same error:

spark-shell --packages com.ibm.SparkTC:spark-netezza_2.10:0.1.1 --driver-class-path /path/to/nzjdbc.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 1st idea is right, I think. You almost certainly need to install the Netezza JDBC driver if you have not done this already.

From the link you posted:

> This package can be deployed as part of an application program or from
>   Spark tools such as spark-shell, spark-sql. To use the package in the
>   application, you have to specify it in your application’s build
>   dependency. When using from Spark tools, add the package using
>   –packages command line option. *Netezza JDBC driver also should be
>   added to the application dependencies*.

The Netezza driver is something you have to download yourself, and you need support entitlement to get access to it (via IBM's Fix Central or Passport Advantage).  It is included in either the Windows driver/client support package, or the linux driver package.

Comment: Confirmed, once I installed the proper Netezza JDBC driver, I simply pointed IntelliJ to the nzjdbc.jar file in the Project Structure dependencies and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!